# Which of the following is/are true about nonces/timestamps?

Tags: nonce, timestamping

a. A nonce may or may not be predictable.

b. Use of timestamps requires fewer numbers of messages compared to nonce-only authentication
protocols.

c. Server keeps track of nonce it has used in the past.

d. Timestamp based protocols are sensitive to clock skew.

From the above options which option are true about the question asked

Comment: This seems like homework... What is unclear?

Comment: To the OP: at the very least, state what options there is doubt about, and why. Otherwise the question will be closed as a dump of homework, per our [advertised policy on that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also, some of the points are open to a degree of interpretation (analogy for d: tires are sensitive to nails). I hate MCQs when not carefully thought.